# what is Yii::app() in php framework yii

Tags: php, yii

I am new to yii. I want to know about `Yii::app()`. I searched for it, but I am not able to understand it exactly.

Comment: This represents the entire application singleton. It may also be null under certain circumstances as well.

Comment: does it mean, it represents complete application's parent object? please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: That is exactly what it means.

Comment: Thaks for your reply. I was stuck by just reading docs, one more thing, as per the documentation - Yii::app()->user->name will give the name of the logged in user ?

Comment: I don't use Yii anymore, and it's been awhile, but if I remember correctly it's actually `Yii::app()->user->id` that returns the username and if you want to use `Yii:app()->user->name` you need to use `setState('name', $model->name);` where `$model->name` is derived from your `UserIdentity` model

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Please read information from this link.You will understand it.

[YII Documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/6/how-to-add-more-information-to-yii-app-user/)

Answer (score 7):

Yii is the `Yii` singleton: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/Yii

`Yii::app()` returns the instance of CApplication: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication

Which has many handy methods and variables such as user (referenced by `Yii::app()->user` which was information about the user)

Comment: I don't understand why Yii::$app isn't used everywhere instead of Yii::app(). Why waste a method call just to return the variable?

Answer (score 1):

The application object encapsulates the execution context within which a request is processed. Its main task is to collect some basic information about the request, and dispatch it to an appropriate controller for further processing. It also serves as the central place for keeping application-level configuration settings. For this reason, the application object is also called the front-controller.

The application object is instantiated as a singleton by the entry script. The application singleton can be accessed at any place via `Yii::app()`.